# How do I replace nulls in one column with values in another column in the same dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

My df in R has the following column contents (all char):

- ColumnA - point-of-origin names
- ColumnB - destination names
- ColumnC - start coordinates
- ColumnD - end coordinates

```
my_df <- structure(list(origin = c("AAA", "", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"), destin = c("BBB", "FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "III"), start_coord = c("1.1", "2.2", "3.3", "4.4", "5.5"), end_coord = c("2.2", "6.6", "7.7", "8.8", "9.9" )), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are rows with empty strings in ColumnA. I want to replace the empty strings with values from ColumnB where ColumnC values match ColumnD values. The expected output for the missing value in the example above is BBB. How can I arrive at this? I'm new to R. Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It'd be helpful if you'd post a small sample of your data here. You can do that easily with `dput(head(dataframe_name)`.

Comment: structure(list(origin = c("AAA", "", "CCC", "DDD", "EEE"), destin = c("BBB", 
"FFF", "GGG", "HHH", "III"), start_coord = c("1.1", "2.2", "3.3", 
"4.4", "5.5"), end_coord = c("2.2", "6.6", "7.7", "8.8", "9.9"
)), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Thanks for posting that. Even better, add it to the question body, above. Also, it's helpful to see what your desired output would be. Given the data you just posted, what would be the value of the empty value in the 2nd observation? Would it be BBB?

Comment: Yes, the desired value would be BBB. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there's a cleaner way to do this, but at first blush I'd be inclined to replace the blanks with a lookup using `match()`. If `origin` is non-blank, we just use `origin` otherwise we get the `destin` value for where the `start_coord` matches the `end_coord`:

```
df$origin <- ifelse(
  df$origin != "", 
  df$origin, 
  df$destin[match(df$start_coord, df$end_coord)]
)
```